# Cardinality of $\bigoplus\limits_{i=1}^\infty\mathbb Z$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Cardinality of $\bigoplus\limits_{i=1}^\infty\mathbb Z$.

First it is uncountable (don't know how to show it), but is it equal to $2^{\aleph_0}$ or $\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}$ ? I don't want to just write $\aleph_1$, it should have some relation to $\aleph_0$

Comment: Note that $2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_0^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: You say you know it's uncountable, but not how to show it. My friend, you should look up Cantor's diagonal argument.

Comment: @Arthur infinitely many copies of $\mathbb Z$, and yes both can be equal  (as the uncountability is not further classified, as far as I know), but which of them does correspond better to the construction ?

Comment: It's countable by the usual definition of $\bigoplus_{1}^{\infty} \mathbb Z$.

Comment: For example, $(1,1,1,1,\dots)$ is not usually considered a memeber of $\bigoplus_{1}^\infty \mathbb Z$.

Comment: @user314 : $\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} \Bbb Z$ is uncountable, but the direct sum is countable.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews can you elaborate, but if the index were finite then it would be an element ?

Comment: The direct sum is the group of elements $(a_1,a_2,\dots)$ where only finitely many of the $a_i$ are non-zero.

Comment: You do not appear aware of what some of the symbols in your question mean. Do not just use them. For example, it makes little sense to mention  $\aleph_1$ in the context that you do.

Answer (score 1):

You should proof that a countable union of countable sets is countable.Then you should proof that finite products of countable sets are countable.

Now you have everything you need. Just prove:

$$ \bigoplus_{i=1}^{\infty} \Bbb Z = \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} \Bbb Z^i. $$